# Change position of div on hover

Tags: html, css

Consider following HTML.
I have `.image` and `.details` wrapped in `.wrap`. Outside the `.wrap`, I have another div `.extra`, which I want to hide initially but on hover over the **image div only**, i want to slide it down so that it takes **whole area** of the `.wrap`.

I am trying following code, does not work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8075/8310628243_d48e64dc66_m.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="details">xxx</div>
    </div>

    <div class="extra">hidden, show on hover over .image</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 240px;       
}

.image{
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;     
}

.extra{
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
}

.box .image:hover .extra{
    top: 0;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pv9jd/

Comment: Not sure what is the `.overlay` class, did you mean `.extra` ?

Comment: yes, sorry, that was a mistake as I copied some code. But I updated it above.

Comment: @user1251698 - what exactly do you mean by sliding `.extra`??

Comment: @PankitKapadia I meant, initially the .extra position is -100%, on hover i want to change its position to 0, and use css transition for the sliding effect. but the problem in above question is that the .extra position does not change on hover.

Comment: @user1251698 - would you mind using JQuery for sliding effect?

Comment: @user1251698 - without JS you can do something like this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pv9jd/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.extra` is not a child of `.image`.

I updated the fiddle by replacing `.image` with `.wrap:hover`.

http://jsfiddle.net/UrKCs/2/

I'm not sure if you want that, because now the `.extra` appears when hovering the whole `.wrap` div.

I updated it again to have the hover on the image only

http://jsfiddle.net/UrKCs/5/

Comment: Thanks, your second example is what im looking for. It works fine in your example, but if i set the height of the .extra to 100%, it creates the problem. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/UrKCs/9/ Take the cursor on the image, you will see that it does not appear smoothly, instead it keep flashing/blinking. Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: Alright, I updated the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/UrKCs/10/ It wasn't working because our property css was saying to show `.extra` only when :hover .image, so I added `.extra:hover` property as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this [image hover using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/UrKCs/7/)

```
$('.image').hover(function(){
  $('.extra').css({'top' : '0'});
    },function(){
      $('.extra').css({'top' : '-100%'}
  );
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to butcher your code but this may be able to help you:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.box div{
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: border .7s ease;
}
.image{
  background: #fff url(http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8075/8310628243_d48e64dc66_m.jpg) bottom;
  border-top: solid 100px #ccc;
}

.image:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
  border: solid 0px;
}
```

You can read more [here](http://elneco.biz/css-sibling-selector-navigation/) for the sliding.

You can also play around here: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/oqxJu